# Error message when leaving role blank is quite difficult to read

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, old-teams, error-message

As always, a beautiful picture is worth more than a thousand words, especially those which can not be read.
[image: The error message ponders upon its purpose, its reason to exist]

`.message.message-error` has a `color: white`, which may be fitting for other places, but not quite here.

Comment: Surely the actual problem is the missing dark red background color on that error popup.

Comment: lol, white font on white background is just perfect for my error messages :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yikes. Thanks for spotting this. Also found that we were over-writing `.message-info` popovers as well. Fixes for both will be going on out on the next build today. I will update this post with the correct status once the changes are live.